# Pipelining ajax http requests and execute the success function on Latest request only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax api to call a web method, and on `success` i am implementing a functionality like `showHideDomElement`.

```
function showHideDomElement(data) 
{
      if(data == 1 )
          $('#selector').show();
      else
          $('#selector').hide();
}
```

and this is how i call it

```
function Validatebatch() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: getControllerURL("/Invoice") + "/ValidateBatch",
    data: {
      "Id": $('#someselector').val()
    },
    async: true, // i tried with 'false' but it affect performance
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      showHideDomElement(data);
    }
  });
}
```

The ajax request to `Validatebatch` function raised multiple times, so there are multiple active http request pointing the `url` completing at different time.

Due to Asynchronous behavior, the `success callback` can execute at different orders.

The order of finishing up is creating the problem. Please suggest a way that can bound the ajax request to behave/complete in the order it is executed (Please suggest other than jquery `async` property)

Thanks

Comment: how and where do you launch `Validatebatch()` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of, you have to rewrite your Validatebatch function so it return the Promise generated by the $.ajax call, e.g.:

```
function Validatebatch() {
  return $.ajax({
```

then you must store the promise of each Validatebatch call and use it to trigger the next Validatebatch only after the previous has completed, you should have something like:

```
promise = Validatebatch(); // call Validatebatch the first time and store the returned Promise object

promise = promise.then(Validatebatch); // another call to Validatebatch, only triggered after the previous has ended

promise = promise.then(Validatebatch); // again, this third Validatebatch call will only happen after the second one has ended.
```